# SQLServer 2008 services broken after Visual Studio 2015 installation (sqlcmd shows nothing)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio

This is my SQL Server. MSSQL 2008 (not R2):

> Sql Server 2008   MSSQLSERVER MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER Database Engine
>   Services  1033        **10.0.1600.22**

After installing Visual Studio 2015 with SQL tools. The result was something went seriously wrong (I think because of lack of admin permissions on the computer).

sqlcmd -L shows NO services

[image: . It waits a while, then empty.]

The SQLServerManager10 works and that's the SQL Server Configuration Manager. However you get error: after requesting WMI provider requesting data:

the remote procedure call failed [0x800706be]

[image]

So you can't click on Services to see your MSSQL services.

SQL Server Management Studio continues to work FINE. However, VS2015 projects cannot connect to the database:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"}

I'm hoping this isn't an unrelated issue due to IIS 7 users not having permissions to the SQL server. All TCP/IP, named, & other pipes are open.

My buddy did the same VS2015 installation, but everything works for him because he initially had SQLEXPRESS SQL Server 2008 R2 not MSSQL non-R2 service.

I tried installing SP1, SP2, SP3 for SQL Server 2008, but I think it's not installing properly, because nothing changes (still **10.0.1600.22**). Maybe some sort of administrator permission issue on my computer. My plan is to reinstall everything with admin permissions properly unless someone has a better idea.

Config-checker says:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid [mainstream support has ended for your version of SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/). As such it'll be very hard to troubleshoot a co-installation of Visual studio 2015 and SQL Server. Especially if I my guess is correct and you're using a client computer.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a variety of reasons why this is going wrong.
Most of which are related to the SQL Server components installed with VS2015.

When VS2015 is installed, the default behavior is to also install the SQL Server data tools.
These need to be compatible with the version of SQL Server that you're currently running.

What I would do to troubleshoot your situation is:

- Check if the SQL Server Services aren't disabled in the services.msc
- Try to upgrade your SQL Server version to the latest service pack
- Perform a clean install of the highest SQL Server version you can utilize

  - Make sure you have backups or a copy of your ldf/mdf files (as it sounds like you're working from a development environment, your main concern is probably not data recovery)
  - Uninstall every component of your current SQL Server installation
  - Reboot
  - Install the latest version of SQL Server that your work allows

Comment: Yes I just need to scrub clean this system I feel like. Maybe just decide to also rebuild the database brand new, just copy over the data and data structures to a new database (but there's several so I've avoided it).

The latest service pack I think failed for me, because for other people this fixes the problem, I think it's a permission thing. I am using corporate stuff so that means lack of admin permissions.

Thanks for the succinct advice.